# Vertical center inside div

Tags: html, css, alignment

Having a problem vertically centering my span inside my div.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="rcontainer" style="width:100px;">
    <div id="accinfo" style="height:50px; overflow:hidden;">
        <img src="images/default-avatar.png" id="accavatar" />
        <span id="inneraccinfo">
            Level X <br />
            Win/loss X
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#accavatar {
resize:both;
width:50px;}
#accinfo {
position: relative;
left: 10px;
top: 10px;
display: inline;}
#inneraccinfo {
font-family:my_fat_font;
color: white;}
```

Fiddle, with about the same structure:
http://jsfiddle.net/6jnte8da/1/

I want to vertically align the span element incasing "level x" & "win/loss X", with respect to the image.

In advance - Thank you

Comment: create a fiddle if you want people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `display:table-cell` in conjunction with `display:table` for parent. 
Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6jnte8da/2/

Answer (score 0):

Remove all style tags from HTML

```
<div id="rcontainer">
    <div id="accinfo">
        <img src="images/default-avatar.png" id="accavatar" />
        <span id="inneraccinfo">
            Level X <br />
            Win/loss X
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And try something like this for css

```
#rcontainer {
    height: 50px;
}
#accavatar {
    width:50px;
}
#accinfo {
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
#accinfo img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
#inneraccinfo {
    font-family:my_fat_font;
    color: white;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This does not vertically align the span with respect to the image.

Comment: Sorry, I should propably mention that I'm looking to get the span vertically CENTERED.